# What is the difference between the .wav and .gsm file format

Tags: asterisk

I am learning asterisk.In this I have worked with voicemail application.
 When I was trying to play the voicemail,I have seen the files in the following format.

```
   .wav
   .WAV
   .gsm
```

What is the difference between the above file formats.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is info on [Asterisk wiki](http://www.voip-info.org/tiki-index.php?page=Convert+WAV+audio+files+for+use+in+Asterisk):

```
gsm: raw gsm encoding, good for VoIP 
wav: MS wav format, 16 bit linear 
WAV: MS wav format, gsm encoded (wav49)
```

You can read about those file formats on Wikipedia: [Audio_file_format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_file_format)
Remember that `.wav` files can be created with various codecs.

On Asterisk wiki there is [article about sound files](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+sound+files) with information about converting `.wav` to `.gsm` and tools that can be used with those files.